# How to pass Laravel Spatie Roles and Permission into Vue component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using Laravel Spatie Roles and Permission package to add authorization to my Laravel Vue3 web app.
I have an issue in passing the user roles and permissions in the Vue component to check if the user is authorized to do certain tasks.
To pass the permissions in the Vue template I used the following package.
[laravel-permission-to-vuejs](https://github.com/ahmedsaoud31/laravel-permission-to-vuejs) I followed all the steps as defined on the GitHub page.

in main layout app.blade.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.Laravel = {
        csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        jsPermissions: {!! auth()->check()?auth()->user()->jsPermissions():0 !!}
    }
 </script>
```

in app.js

```
import LaravelPermissionToVueJS from 'laravel-permission-to-vuejs'

app.use(router, LaravelPermissionToVueJS);
```

in user model

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasPermissions;
use LaravelAndVueJS\Traits\LaravelPermissionToVueJS;

    use LaravelPermissionToVueJS;
    use HasRoles;
    use HasPermissions;
```

in Vue template file this is just a dummy template with no extra code, I just want to check if this hides and shows according to user-granted permissions. Once it clears the checking of the permissions, I may expand it further.

```
<template>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 bg-info" v-if="can('create contracts')">
          <div class="small-box bg-default">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3>65</h3>
              <h3 class="fz-half">Own Vehicle</h3>
              <span class="fz-4 p-absolute"
                ><i class="fas fa-car-alt"></i
              ></span>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps, onMounted } from "vue";
</script>
```

When I use `v-if="can('some permission')"` its returns this error

[image]

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you show us your vue component fully and how you use it in the app?

Comment: I have created a testing Vue component with no extra code, just to check if it's working properly

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it passing the roles through Inertia.

This way you also don't have to pass anything through *app.blade.php*

You need Inertia to use this fix.

add this to your
*app.js*

```
import LaravelPermissionToVueJS from '../js/LaravelPermissions';
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.use(plugin);
Vue.use(LaravelPermissionToVueJS);
```

*LaravelPermissions.js* (his file but changed it a little)

```
export default {
install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.prototype.can = function(value){
        // var permissions = window.Laravel.jsPermissions.permissions;
        var permissions = this.$page.props.permissions.permissions
        var _return = false;
        if(!Array.isArray(permissions)){
            return false;
        }
        if(value.includes('|')){
            value.split('|').forEach(function (item) {
                if(permissions.includes(item.trim())){
                    _return = true;
                }
            });
        }else if(value.includes('&')){
            _return = true;
            value.split('&').forEach(function (item) {
                if(!permissions.includes(item.trim())){
                    _return = false;
                }
            });
        }else{
            _return = permissions.includes(value.trim());
        }
        return _return;
    }
    
    Vue.prototype.is = function(value){
        // var roles = window.Laravel.jsPermissions.roles;
        var roles = this.$page.props.permissions.roles;
        var _return = false;
        
        if(!Array.isArray(roles)){
            return false;
        }
        if(value.includes('|')){
            value.split('|').forEach(function (item) {
                if(roles.includes(item.trim())){
                    _return = true;
                }
            });
        }else if(value.includes('&')){
            _return = true;
            value.split('&').forEach(function (item) {
                if(!roles.includes(item.trim())){
                    _return = false;
                }
            });
        }else{
            _return = roles.includes(value.trim());
        }
        return _return;
    }
}
```

}

*HandleInertiaRequest.php* (this is where we pass the roles and permissions as props.)

```
public function share(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
        'permissions' => json_decode(auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->jsPermissions() : '{}', true),
    ]);
}
```

Now you should be able to use

> v-if="can('some permission')"